# Python Function not returning

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and am learning how it works through doing the exercises from project euler. Problem 2 is focused on the Fibonacci sequence for which I've created this recursive function:

```
def CalcFb(start,end):
    if (end<=4000000):
        CalcFb(end,start+end)
    else:
        print "Returning:",end
        return end

print "Answer: {0}".format(CalcFb(start,start+1))
```

When I run the program I get the following output:

```
Returning: 5702887
Answer: None
```

I'm calling the function with:

```
start=1
```

I don't understand why "None" is being printed it should have printed 5702887. Can someone please help me to understand why this is happeneing?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: @Lafada  The editing you made to the question is *harmful*: you fixed (a part of) what was broken in the code, making the output posted by the O.P. not to actually mathc the code in the question. This can make several people willing to help waste several minutes trying to figure out what went on. Please, be careful when editing. It is OK for code in question to be broken - that is why the questions are placed.

Comment: sure, next time I will make sure it will be not harmful :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the return statement in the if-clause:

```
if (end<=4000000):
    return CalcFb(end,start+end)
```

Otherwise you call your function recursively but only the *last* call returns a value and the second-to-last one does *not* return anything.

Comment: Well spotted. Many thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You are not returning any value when recursing...

```
def CalcFb(start,end):
    if (end<=4000000):
        return CalcFb(end,start+end)   ### this needs to return a value as well
    else:
        print "Returning:",end
        return end
```

Answer (score -2):

for me its return `2`

```
>>> def CalcFb(start,end):
...     if (end<=4000000):
...         CalcFb(end,start+end)
...     else:
...         print "Returning:",end
...     return end
...
>>>
>>> start=1
>>> print "Answer: {0}".format(CalcFb(start,start+1))
Returning: 5702887
Answer: 2
```

Check indent.

Comment: It returns "2" after yu change the code to bring the "return" statement to outside the "else" clause. Please, do changes on *your* code when answering, not to the code posted in the question.

Comment: Ignore my comment - didn't realise OP's code had been edited before I first saw it!